# Change transparency of points in a legend

Tags: r, igraph

I have plotted a network plot with igraph. The opacity of the vertices is reduced to 0.5.

Now I would like to add a legend to the plot manually, where the points have the same color/transparency as the vertices in the plot.

```
plot(g, vertex.color = adjustcolor(V(g)$color, alpha = 0.5))
legend('topleft',legend = names, pt.cex = 2, pch = 21, pt.bg = colors)
```

How can I alter the transparency of the points in the legend?

Comment: `pt.bg = adjustcolor(colors, alpha = 0.5)` ?

Comment: @G5W - add as answer? So far as I can tell this isn't a duplicate

Comment: Thank you. If you add as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not provide data, I make up some sample data. Also,  both "names" and "colors" are the names of R functions so I changed them to "Names" and "Colors".

You can make the adjustment that you want just by using `adjustcolor` again.

```
library(igraph)

## Some sample data
set.seed(1234)
g = erdos.renyi.game(10, 0.3)
Colors = rainbow(4)
V(g)$color = sample(Colors,10, replace=TRUE)
Names = paste("N", 1:4, sep="")

## Your plot and adjusted legend
plot(g, vertex.color = adjustcolor(V(g)$color, alpha = 0.5))
legend('topleft', legend = Names, pt.cex = 2, pch = 21, 
    pt.bg = adjustcolor(Colors, alpha = 0.5))
```

[image: Plot with labels]